# Python tweepy api.user_timeline for list of multiple users error

Tags: python, rest, twitter, indentation, tweepy

I've modified the code below to try and run it for a list of multiple user names, but keep getting the following error :"File "testing1.py", line 19
    def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

If I move

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as targets_file:
    targets_list = targets_file.readlines()

usernames = [] 

for item in targets_list:
    usernames.append(item.strip('\n')
```

after "pass", then I get the following error: "File "testing1.py", line 65
    if **name** == '**main**':
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Any help is much appreciated!

```
import tweepy 
import csv

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

with open('list.txt', 'r') as targets_file:
     targets_list = targets_file.readlines()

usernames = [] 

for item in targets_list:
     usernames.append(item.strip('\n')

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    #Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with   this method

    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  

    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum   allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

    #transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

    #write the csv  
    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    for x in usernames:
        get_all_tweets(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to close parenthesis:

`for item in targets_list:
     usernames.append(item.strip('\n'))`